# Cut rectangle from page and place to another page by using iText7

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, methods, itext7

I want to copy rectangle sized location and put to another page. E.g. I have 100 pages and i want to cut in 54 page rectangle which is in `x`, `y` and has `width`, `height` cordinates and put it into 3 page.
 My method look like this:

```
public void CopyRect(string filenamePdf, 
                     Rectangle rect, 
                     int sourcePageNumber, 
                     int destinationPageNumber)
{
}
```

- string filenamePdf is my source pdf
- rectangle rect is my cordinates (x,y, width, height)
- int sourcePageNumber is page from where i want to copy that rectangle with information
- int destinantionPageNumber is page where i want to put that rectangle with information.

How should I describe this method? Thank you.

Comment: In your title you say *cut* but in the question body you say *copy*; which do you really want? And where on the target page do you want to put the section? What about annotations?

Comment: sorry for mistake, i want to cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found a solution:

```
 public void CopyRectCopy(string filenamePdf,
                          Rectangle rect,
                          int sourcePageNumber,
                          int destinationPageNumber)
    {
        PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filenamePdf));
        PdfDocument resultPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(newPdfWriter(@"C:\Users\USER123"));
        int pageCounter = srcDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
        Rectangle toMove = rect;
        Rectangle pageSize = srcDoc.GetPage(sourcePageNumber).GetPageSize();
        PdfFormXObject pageXObject = srcDoc.GetPage(sourcePageNumber).CopyAsFormXObject(resultPdfDoc);


        PdfFormXObject formXObjectA = new PdfFormXObject(pageSize);
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCounter; i++)
        {
            //deletes an rectangle from exact page.
            if (i == sourcePageNumber)
            {
                resultPdfDoc.AddNewPage();

                PdfCanvas canvasas = new PdfCanvas(formXObjectA, resultPdfDoc);
                canvasas.Rectangle(0, 0, 595.28, 841.89);
                canvasas.Rectangle(toMove);
                canvasas.EoClip();
                canvasas.EndPath();
                canvasas.AddXObject(pageXObject, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                srcDoc.CopyPagesTo(i, i, resultPdfDoc);
            }

        }
        // Create a formXObject of the area to move.
        PdfFormXObject formXObject2 = new PdfFormXObject(pageSize);
        PdfCanvas canvas2 = new PdfCanvas(formXObject2, resultPdfDoc);
        canvas2.Rectangle(toMove);
        // This method uses the nonzero winding rule to determine which regions lie inside the clipping path.
        canvas2.Clip();
        canvas2.EndPath();
        canvas2.AddXObject(pageXObject, 0, 0);


        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(resultPdfDoc.GetPage(destinationPageNumber));
        PdfCanvas canvass = new PdfCanvas(resultPdfDoc.GetPage(sourcePageNumber));
        // Add the area to move content, shifted 10 points to the left and 2 points to the bottom.
        canvas.AddXObject(formXObject2, 0, -50);
        canvass.AddXObject(formXObjectA, 0, 0);

        srcDoc.Close();
        resultPdfDoc.Close();
    }
```

It cut a rectangle from one page and paste to another.

EDITED.

Comment: As far as I see you don't put the `formXObject1` anywhere. Other than that the solution looks ok. There are some drawbacks, though, in particular your solution is likely to drop annotations and document level information. Depending on your input data that may be ok.